# mod-rewrite to ignore the subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using a mod-rewrite for pretty URLs, meant to run on the domain root. Working fine but now I'm trying to make it run on a subdomain and it keeps giving "500 Internal Server Error".

The subdomain automatically redirects to the folder with that name on my hosting account (**sub.domain.com** shows the content of **domain.com/sub/**). Does it fail because this request is already being mod-rewritten automatically or can I simply change something in the htaccess to address the subdomain instead?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: How exactly are those rules supposed to do what you claim you want to do?

Comment: They send all requests like "domain.com/what/ever/" back to the index.php where i can pickup "what" and "ever" as variables. It works fine when there is no subdomain, but i'm stuck at making it ignore the subdomain.

Comment: There's a lot of config missing here. That rule shouldn't be enough to do what it is you say it does.

Comment: As already mentioned - add your missing configs or make clear, you want to help with new config and don't confuse us with your "current and working setup"

Answer (score 0):

Contact your ISP and check if they are setting the **DocumentRoot** for the sub domains to the  /domain/sub/ directory (it's probable) or alternatively using an internal RewriteRule to direct traffic to that directory (you can see if there's an external rewrite / redirect in place via Chrome or Firefox + firebug, use the developer tools to check the response header, on the network Tab). If they have set the document root you will need to copy or symbolically link **ALL** the files you want accessible via the sub-domain, to the /domain.com/sub/ directory  e.g. the **.htaccess, index.php, images, js** and **css** files and sub directories. If they are using an internal rewrite, a quick tweak to your own existing internal rewrite, in the existing .htaccess file, should suffice e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php  [L]
```